# How to create a Google BigQuery table using a CSV file stored in GCS without the file's header?

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to create a table by using a `CSV` file, without the columns (`CSV` header) being part of the 1st row. I've tried with the following `bq` CLI commands:

- With the following command, the first row contains my `CSV` file
  header:

  ```
  bq load --autodetect --source_format=CSV --allow_quoted_newlines=true ARADMIN.B1731 gs://new007/B1731.csv
  ```
- With this one, the file's header is not present:

  ```
  bq load --autodetect --source_format=CSV --allow_quoted_newlines=true --skip_leading_rows=1 ARADMIN.B1731 gs://new007/B1731.csv
  ```

But the file's header appears at the 1st row. How can I solve this issue?

[image: loaded data set into BigQuery]

**Sample data set**

[updated download data set](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vu9pF3Q6dwA_TB7CadiR-sWx8VqQ-Erj/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Do you mean that, in the second case, your column are not named as your header label?

Answer (score 3):

BigQuery infers headers by comparing the first row of the file with other rows in the data set. If the first line contains only strings, and the other lines do not, BigQuery assumes that the first row is a header row.

Check the data in the file. If file does not have header, then no need to skip first row `--skip_leading_rows=1`.

Comment: i already tried but not working.. in data set, only one coloum has values others columns are empty. I think.. that's why all header come down in row 1 position. Still waiting for solution. Kindly help anyone how can i fix this.

Comment: As suggested by @Vikram, if the CSV file does not contain any headers you can drop the `--skip_leading_rows=1` flag. I have tested this with the command `bq load --autodetect --source_format=CSV DATASET_NAME.TABLE_NAME gs://BUCKET_NAME/test.csv`.

Comment: @AnjaliRao, can you paste sample test data to work on ?. I have tested and its still working

Comment: @Vikram i have attached screenshot of loaded data set into BigQuery. You can see that "C1" , C03.... columns are part of 1st row.

Comment: @Anjali Rao, can you provide a sample of the CSV file you are trying to import?

Comment: @JuanFernándezAfonso pls find attached data sample

Comment: @AnjaliRao, The sample data is not accessible.

Comment: @AnjaliRao, [CSV data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vu9pF3Q6dwA_TB7CadiR-sWx8VqQ-Erj/view) I see that there is only one column filled with values. The rest of the columns are empty. If you use the suggested command, Bigquery will read all the columns of the CSV file skiping the first line containing the headers and it will fill the table with the rest of the values. Keep in mind that the "empty" values of the CSV files are interpreted as NULLS. I think that what you are obtaining is the expected result.

Comment: Agree with @JuanFernándezAfonso, this is expected result. The empty columns are interpreted as empty. You can specify schema while uploading the csv instead of `--autodetect` flag